# Laptop takes a long time to START booting

Tags: boot, laptop, acer-travelmate

I have an Acer TravelMate B117-M-C1W5 Notebook Qua which worked reliably for over 3 years, apart from the battery always mysteriously draining completely within a week of it being entirely shut off.

However, for a few months now it was very difficult to get it to start. Before the problem started, the instance the power button got pressed, the display showed the Acer logo (BIOS screen) with the operating system starting to boot shortly after. Now this sometimes works just the same as it used to do but most of the time I was unable to get it to start. After pressing the power button, the display remained completely black (not even the backlight turned on). The only thing that happened was that one of its LEDs started flashing. I then turned it off (pressing the power button for 6 seconds) and back on again repeatedly, sometimes 20 times before it finally started up.

However, I recently have noticed that it does start up reliably given enough time. It will take up to about 5 minutes to start doing anything; then it will boot up normally. As implied before, as soon as the Acer BIOS screen is displayed, the rest of the boot process happens at normal speed.

It also seems to me that the time it takes to start booting is loosely correlated with the amount of time it was shut off for.

Rebooting and waking up from standby works 100% reliably without delay.

I already reset the BIOS settings to the default and re-installed the operating system for good measure. On the off chance that the OS matters: Manjaro

What causes the boot delay on this computer?

Edit: The situation has worsened from 5 minutes to well over an hour.

Comment: Is the battery detachable? Can you detach it and see if it changes anything?

Comment: No, the battery is built-in. However, if I connect it to the grid before or while trying to get it to start, that doesn't change anything. It seems to take the same amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds very much like the battery is really stuffed and drawing so much power when the system tries to start [and the battery is empty ] that the system is deprived of sufficient power to boot (which is a relatively high power draw time).

(I note that batteries with dead cells - and I'm guessing yours has at least 2) cab draw quite a lot of power to try recharge, while at the same time depleting other batteries. This is the core of your problem)

You can test this theory by leaving the power plugged in when the system is not in use and seeing if the system boots first time.

Comment: I have plugged it in and have left it plugged in ever since shortly after you posted your answer. I already thought you were on to something when yesterday it started booting after only 2 minutes when it was plugged in for 2 hours straight. The battery indicator indicated full charge a good amount of time prior to that. But I left it plugged in over night and this morning it took a solid 5:35 minutes to start booting. Btw this laptop's battery life is actually great. It was advertised as lasting 12 hours and it actually still lasts longer despite being over 3 years old.